# Who determines, and how, the composition of the S&P 500 index?

Tags: etf, index-fund, market-indexes, standard-and-poors-500

I thought S&P 500 would contain the top 500 U.S. companies by market cap, but apparently that is not the case?

e.g., Facebook (FB) was only recently added and has market cap of $100B whereas LabCorp (LH) is currently a S&P 500 member ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S&P_500_companies)) and has market capitalization of less than $10B.

Is there a simple rule or formula determining what companies make up the S&P 500?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The S&P 500 index is maintained by S&P Dow Jones Indices, a division of McGraw Hill Financial. Changes to the index are made periodically, as needed.  For Facebook, you'll find it mentioned in this [December 11, 2013 press release (PDF)](https://www.spice-indices.com/idpfiles/spice-assets/resources/public/documents/67155_fbshuf252426100.pdf).  Quote:

> **New York, NY, December 11 , 2013 –** S&P Dow Jones Indices will make the following changes to the S&P 100, S&P 500, MidCap 400
>   and S&P SmallCap 600 indices after the close of trading on Friday,
>   December 20:
>
> - Facebook Inc. (NASD:FB) will replace The Williams Companies Inc. (NYSE:WMB) in the S&P 100, and Facebook will replace Teradyne Inc.
>     (NYSE:TER) in the S&P 500 [...]

You can find out more about the S&P 500 index eligibility criteria from the [S&P U.S. Indices methodology document (PDF)](http://ca.spindices.com/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-us-indices.pdf).  See pages 5 and 6:

> ### Eligibility Criteria
>
> #### Additions - S&P 500, S&P MidCap 400 and S&P SmallCap 600 Market Capitalization.
>
> **Market Capitalization** - [...]
>
> **Liquidity** - [...]
>
> **Domicile** - [...]
>
> **Public Float** - [...]
>
> **Sector Classification** - [...]
>
> **Financial Viability** - Usually measured as four consecutive quarters of positive as
>   reported earnings. [...]
>
> **Treatment of IPOs** - Initial public offerings should be seasoned for 6 to 12 months
>   before being considered for addition to an index.
>
> **Eligible Securities** - [...]
>   [...]
>
> #### Timing of Changes
>
> Changes to the U.S. indices other than the TMIX are made as needed,
>   with no annual or  semi-annual reconstitution. [...]

LabCorp may have a smaller market cap than Facebook, but Facebook didn't meet all of the eligibility criteria – for instance, see the above note about "Treatment of IPOs" – until recently.

Note also that *"Initial public offerings should be seasoned for 6 to 12 months"* implies somebody at S&P makes a decision as to the exact *when*.

As such, I would say, no, there is no "simple rule or formula", just the methodology above as applied by the decision-makers at S&P.

Answer (score 3):

[S & P's site](http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-500) has a methodology link that contains the following which may be of use:

> Market Capitalization. Unadjusted market capitalization of US$ 4.6
>   billion or more for  the S&P 500, US$ 1.2 billion to US$ 5.1 billion
>   for the S&P MidCap 400, and US$ 350  million to US$ 1.6 billion for
>   the S&P SmallCap 600. The market cap of a potential  addition to an
>   index is looked at in the context of its short- and medium-term
>   historical  trends, as well as those of its industry. These ranges are
>   reviewed from time to time to  assure consistency with market
>   conditions.
>
> Liquidity. Adequate liquidity and reasonable price – the
>   ratio of annual dollar value  traded to float adjusted market
>   capitalization should be 1.00 or greater, and the company  should
>   trade a minimum of 250,000 shares in each of the six months leading up
>   to the  evaluation date.
>
> Domicile. U.S. companies. For index purposes,
>   a U.S. company has the following  characteristics:
>
> 1. File 10-K annual reports and should not be considered a foreign entity by the  SEC.
> 2. The U.S. portion of fixed assets and revenues constitutes a plurality of the total,  but need not exceed 50%. When these factors
>      are in conflict, assets determine  plurality. Revenue determines
>      plurality when there is incomplete asset  information.
> 3. The primary listing of the common stock is the NYSE (including NYSE Arca  and NYSE MKT), the NASDAQ Global Select Market, the NASDAQ
>      Select  Market or the NASDAQ Capital Market. ADRs are not eligible for
>      inclusion.
> 4. A corporate governance structure consistent with U.S. practice. If criteria #2 is not met or is ambiguous, S&P Dow Jones Indices may
>      still deem it a U.S.  company for index purposes if its primary
>      listing, headquarters and incorporation are all  in the U.S. and/or a
>      “domicile of convenience” (see Appendix A). In situations where the
>      only factor suggesting that a company is not a U.S. company is its 
>      tax registration in a “domicile of convenience” or another location
>      chosen for tax-related  reasons, S&P Dow Jones Indices normally
>      determines that the company is still a U.S.  company.
>
> The final determination of domicile eligibility is made by the U.S.
>   Index Committee.