# Constituents of S&P 500 Top 50?

Tags: index-fund

Try as I might I can't find the current constituents of the S&P 500 Top 50 index: http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-500-top-50

That link only lists the top 10 constituents by weighting. And there is a Guggenheim fund that tracks it which lists all 50 constituents but I'd like to get the list from an official source/S&P 500.

Comment: See also [Who determines, and how, the composition of the S&P 500 index?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/27332/35567).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of all S&P 500 constituents by weighting:
https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500

However, the S&P 500 Top 50 constituents are only changed once per year, in June. Furthermore, they use an algorithm intended to reduce volatility, which could in theory (it seems to me) prevent a stock that shot from nothing into the top 50, from ever appearing in the index. https://us.spindices.com/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-us-indices.pdf

The Guggenheim fund was the only one I could find that tracks this particular index, so that might be your best bet. Given that it only changes once a year, the Guggenheim fund shouldn't have any tracking errors.

Comment: I agree with all of this. I'm still hoping that I can find a Standard & Poor's source that lists the constituents instead of relying on Guggenheim.

Comment: @user128807 Well, if it's any consolation, another human tried to find that information and failed too.